# Getting cursor coordinates in mousemove event javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get coordinates of cursor position in mousemove and mouseup`s handlers?

```
conDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", mDown, false);
conDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", mUp, false); 
conDiv.addEventListener("mousemove", mMove, false);
```

using function mDown(target) I can get coordinates of point where mouse button was clicked

```
function mDown(target) {
    x1 = target.clientX;
    y1 = target.clientY;
    console.log("y1 ->> " + y1);
    console.log("x1 ->> " + x1);
}
```

I need to get the coordinates of cursor in mUp (handler of mouseup) and mMove (handler of mousemove)
How can I do that?

```
function mUp(tareget){
     x2 = target.clientX; // warning: target is not difined the same situation in nMove
     y2 = target.clientY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same, but you have a typo in your function:

```
function mUp(tareget){ // here use target instead of tareget!!!
     x2 = target.clientX; // warning: target is not difined the same situation in nMove
     y2 = target.clientY;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have already found this mistake. thank you for help))